# Total derivative and partial derivative of an equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, differential

Will an equation still be valid if we take total derivative of both side? What about partial derivative instead?

For example, suppose we have $\varphi (s, \varphi(t,x)) = \varphi(s+t,x)$, does that mean $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (s, \varphi(t,x)) = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (s+t,x)$? What about $\frac{d \varphi}{ds} (s, \varphi(t,x)) = \frac{d \varphi}{d s} (s+t,x)$?

Comment: If $A=B$ then anything (single-valued) you perform on both sides will give you another equality.

Comment: The answer is no. Let's use a simple example, in one dimension: $x^2=1$. This has solutions $\pm 1$. Take the derivative with respect to $x$ and you get $2x=0$, which implies $x=0$. A geometrical interpretation means that two curves intersect, but the slopes can be different. The slopes are the same only in a special case, when curves are tangent.